# type object DbTableExternal has no attribute db_path

Tags: python

I have this abstract class

```
class DbTableCore(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def create_table(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def drop_table(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def insert_items(self, items):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def select_items(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def update_items(items):
        pass
```

I wanted to pass some attributes to all child classes, but I heard that using abstract classes. I am unable to do it - attributes do not inherited.

So I decided to create intermediate class which does not implement methods of abstract class - I simply `pass` them

```
class DbTableExternal(DbTableCore):

    def __init__(self):
        with open('app_config.ini') as file:
            cfg = process_ini(tuple(file))
            self.db_path = cfg.get('db_path')

    def create_table(self):
        pass

    def drop_table(self):
        pass

    def insert_items(self, items):
        pass

    def select_items(self):
        pass

    def update_items(items):
        pass
```

And finally my child classes inherit this intermediate class

```
class ItemTable(DbTableExternal):

    def __init__(self):
        DbTableExternal.__init__(self)
        self.db_path = DbTableExternal.db_path
```

But when I try to run it - I've got an error

```
File "bla-bla", line 63, in __init__
  self.db_path = DbTableExternal.db_path # line 63
AttributeError: type object 'DbTableExternal' has no attribute 'db_path'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.db_path = DbTableExternal.db_path
```

You don't need the above line, because `self.db_path` will be set by super class' `__init__` method. (`DbTableExternal.__init__(self)`)

You can access the attribute as `self.db_path` (as instance attribute), not as `DbTableExternal.db_path` (as class attribute)